# Override specific Map keys and values efficiently without copying the original map?

Tags: java

I have a `HashMap` of 10k+ keys and values. We'll call this map the `originalMap`. There is a where I want to create a new map (or view of the map) with added/deleted/overwritten keys and values, without changing the `originalMap`.

For example, key `A` in `originalMap` has value `foo`, and key `B` in `originalMap` has value `bar`.

I want to create a new map (or view of the map) called `newMap` such that I can override specific keys and values. For example, I might want to override key `A` to have value `baz`.

Therefore when I call `newMap.get(A)`, I expect to get back `baz`.

I might also want to delete key `B`. When I call `newMap.containsKey(B)` it should return false.

Similarly, I might want to add key `C`.

I'm trying to do this efficiently, as right now we're doing a deep copy of the full map to create a new `ImmutableMap` with these overridden values, but this is very slow and memory-consuming due to the size of the map, and this operation must happen frequently.

One approach could be to create a `newMap` as an empty `HashMap` and `putAll` existing keys and values into this map. This is better, but still feels suboptimal because we still are shallow copying everything. Another alternative is a custom Guava `ForwardingMap` implementation, but I'm concerned about respecting all the correct semantics by doing so (i.e. `.containsKey()`, `.keySet()` need to all work correctly).

Is there a more straightforward solution, perhaps using Guava's map utils? Some things to simplify this:

1. The set of overwritten keys and values do not change and are known on map creation
2. `originalMap` will not change over the lifetime of this `newMap`
3. All keys and values are immutable

Comment: I would definitely build a ForwardingMap-based solution here, yes.

Comment: Might a _persistent_ collection be the solution here? Something like https://pcollections.org/?

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks for the answer. My primary concern with the `ForwardingMap` solution is ensuring all the methods needed are implemented correctly. For example if I want it to be mutable I need to make sure I implement both `put` and `putAll`. It shouldn't be too difficult to do this but I just want to get it right.

Comment: Don't forget the `standard` methods provided by `ForwardingMap` to help with that.